# Parsing string commandline parameters input inside running application

Tags: java, string, parsing, parameters, external

I am developing a small student project in java and I have encountered an issue.
Firstly, I would like to show you the idea:

We run main app in commandline, lets say "ems":

```
java -jar ems.jar
ems: Hello, bla bla bla type help to see bla bla bla.
```

and now I would like an user to enter commands with parameters like this (just example)

```
ems: help
ems: list -h
ems: program -h
ems: program -create -n Ping -path "C:\\ping.exe" //-create to add new program record  to DB
ems: program -delete -n Ping  //-delete from DB
ems: list -create -n ListForPinging //-creating new list in DB
ems: list -add -n ListForPinging  -p Ping -host stackoverflow.com -t //-add linking program with list
```

Which will result in executing different methods with some parameters, modifing records in DB and inserting those parameters in DB (for later use). `After executing this list, it will fire up C:\\ping.exe -host stackoverflow.com -t`

The question is: Am I following the right path? How to parse/handle those parameters? Should I go with .split? Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I started with regexp, .split(" "); but its not scalable. Also found some tools like args4j but couldnt get it working. Everything I found is working on parameters of the main program not the "inside" ones. Or maybe Im doing it wrong? No, its not homework. Its my own task to get better at programming.

Comment: what you tried so far ?!

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I started with regexp, .split(" "); but its not scalable. Also found some tools like args4j but couldnt get it working.
Everything I found is working on parameters of the main program not the "inside" ones. Or maybe Im doing it wrong? No, its not homework. Its my own task to get better at programming.

Comment: @Szczepanov when we say homework problem, we don't mean something that a teacher assigns and requires you to do. It means it sounds like you are asking us to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Used HashMap for storing param + name and parsed it by using .split.

Answer (score 0):

You also have Apache Commons CLI which provides you a very good API for parsing and using command line parameters.

See more details here : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Hope this helps.